# jQuery code does not work in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Please check this fiddle and see why it does not work in IE8.

http://jsfiddle.net/mostafatalebi/6WQ9x/

There are two list and one container.

List A is the list of all fields, and the second list is empty.

then there is a container which holds all the sub-branches of of all branches. then by clicking on a branch, the jquery code copies the set of matched elements from the container and clones them into the empty second . This works in FF but fails in IE. you can play with fiddle. Here is the jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){


        $('#branches').children('option').on('click', function(){
            var branch = $(this).val();
            var subholder = $('#subbranch-holder');             
            $('#sub').empty();                                          
            $('#sub').html("<option value='false'>انتخاب زیر شاخه ها</option>");
            // console.log(subholder.children('option').length);
            subholder.children('option').each(function(){
            if($(this).attr('id') == 'par'+branch)
            {                           
                $(this).clone().appendTo("#sub");
            }
            });
        });

});
```

Comment: You're sure the document is ready ?

Comment: edited - does not matter much. yes it is ready

Comment: You should be using jQuery 1.10 for oldIE (IE 6-8 inclusive); the 2.x branch of jQuery removes the cruft needed to support those older browsers.

Comment: @DavidThomas is right. Though we have jQuery 1.10.x now for old IE. jQuery 2.0 dropped support of IE versions < 10. Don't worry though, 1.10 has the exact same API.

Comment: thanks much let me test then

Comment: options do not have click events...

Comment: sorry I checked but the problem does not seems to be this. I also checked my jquery which is 1.10 and I only used 2.2 in fiddle

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery version 1.* instead version 2.*.
And change this line :

```
$('#branches').children('option').on('click', function(){
```

To this :

```
$('#branches').on('change', function(){
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6WQ9x/4/

**EDIT:**
It will be better if you use valid html,so your code will work in other browsers .
See this one :
http://jsfiddle.net/6WQ9x/9/

Comment: sorry it does not work. it clones the code but only the first half of the <option> tag is cloned and the content (which is the title of the option) and the closing tags are cloned. why?

Comment: Duplicate id is not valid,if you valid your html , it will be execute better on browsers .There is no wrong with me.See updated jsfiddle.